# Which repository (URL) for repository file to uppdate the sudo package to newest version?

Tags: package-management, sudo, debian

I'm very new to linux.
Which repository (URL) can i use to update only the sudo package to the newest version (1.9.5p2) by adding the URL to the repository file. I can only update to 1.8.27 on my system.

I'm on Debian 10 but i can't find a tutorial/ repository (URL) for that, where can i find a trusted one?
(https://www.sudo.ws/download.html)

Regards

Answer (score 1):

This site is about questions for Ubuntu (only). You should ask your Debian questions on https://superuser.com/ with tag "Debian".

However, answering generically for Debian-based operating systems: you can't expect arbitrary upstream projects like sudo to provide a Debian package or a Debian package repository. Some do, but even then, adding these willy-nilly can cause harm to your system.

You are supposed to consume package updates from your operating system vendor, in this case Debian. For the stable release they will pick a version of each package and it will stay at that version for the life of the release. Only security issues and important bugs will be fixed, generally as a backport which will not alter the overall version number.

The current version of sudo in Debian buster is [1.8.27-1+deb10u3](https://packages.debian.org/buster/sudo). You can verify what you have with:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep sudo
```

If you have the latest version theh that's as good as you are going to get.

If you have specific need for the latest upstream version, please tell us what that need is.

If you are looking at sudo because of the recent security issue, note that was already fixed in that version of Debian's package. You can verify that from [the changelog](https://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs//main/s/sudo/sudo_1.8.27-1+deb10u3_changelog).

Comment: Thank you, i will also have to do it on Ubuntu. It's because of a link from a colleague which told me to update it. He's sent me the news from golem.de where they say: 
...The ones from the open source project will be improved 1.8.2 to 1.8.32p2 and 1.9.0 to 1.9.5p1 therefore contain the security hole...
I don't really know how to handle it. I'm trying to find a starting point for those kind of things.
He just told me to update it.

Comment: Title was: Memory corruption in sudo allows root privileges (https://www.golem.de/news/security-speicherfehler-in-sudo-ermoeglicht-root-rechte-2101-153705.html)
So i should check, if this problem is fixed on any distribution's updated sudo package that i'm working with, logically?

Comment: You should learn how to check security updates on all operating systems you use. Both Debian and Ubuntu have already pushed out updates for this bug. The list of them is here: https://ubuntu.com/security/notices  the one you want is https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4705-2 but the usual ```apt update; apt upgrade``` process has probably already installed that update for you. Or ```unattended-upgrades``` might have. Check.